# iOS: IB Designables Failed to render and update auto layout

Tags: ios

I have Cocoa Touch Framework where I have custom view marked with @IBDesignable. This framework use some dependencies e.g. Alamofire thorugh Carthage. I use then this framework in my app, but when I use this custom view in the storyboard I get this error:

```
Failed to render and update auto layout status: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire Referenced from: MyFramework.framework
```

The project is compiled and I can run the app and everything works, but in the storyboard I cannot see this view. Does anybody know what can cause this error and how to fix it?